# Integrate QGIS with ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: qgis, asp.net

I'm completely new to GIS and i'm trying to work my way into this. My goal is to integrate a simple map created using QGIS with my asp.net web mvc3 application.
The main objectives would be to show the map on the application as well as performing some operations with the different points and lines (points of interest and roads respectively).

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to achieve this?

Comment: Are you referring to QGIS desktop or QGIS server here? asp.net & QGIS certainly is not a common combination.

Comment: @underdark: I'm referring to a map designed on the QGIS desktop. Would server be a better option?

Answer (score 1):

You simply won't be able to do that with the desktop product. To serve and operate on maps via web you need to develop accordingly using one of the various frameworks available.

The basic GIS/web architecture consists in using a database with spatial support (e.g PostGIS), a webmap server (as QGIS server, MapServer, GeoServer, etc.) and client API that will let you manipulate the map published (such as OpenLayers).

It is possible to integrate ASP.MVC with spatial data, but you will need a new stack of tools to render and manipulate the maps.

Comment: So assuming i have a map designed in GIS, and i want to be able to show and manipulate it (zoom, move, add points, click) on the web (ASP NET MVC3). What would the option you would recomend me? Is there any good tutorial that i can read?

Comment: Assuming you have the raw data (the maps produced in a desktop environment are somewhat static) available in a database or shape or any other geospatial format ,you need to use the tools i've mentioned above to code and create a mapping solution. You should check OpenLayers, Postgresql + PostGIS and MapServer. Without knowing your environment better is hard to tell. SQL Server also has support for spatial types. NHibernate has support for spatial types and multiple dialects (sql server, postgis, etc).

Comment: One more question: assuming i have the map components (.shp, etc). If i load the map this way, will i be able to manipulate in my application, i.e., adding points and so on?